# Docker: Set timeout and Exit with Error Code

Tags: docker, dockerfile, containers

How can make a Docker container exit with an error code after a timeout?

I have a Dockerfile which uses the `ubuntu` image and copies the script file from my directory to image and finally exectues the script in a container.

```sh
FROM ubuntu
WORKDIR /usr/bin/
COPY ./example.py .
RUN chmod +x example.py
ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "example.py"]
```

Then I run the build command:

```sh
docker build -t demo .
```

run the container:

```sh
docker run -it --rm demo
```

I'm not sure how long does it take to successfully execute the example.py script but I want to exit the container after 1 hour.
If the example.py script executed successfully within 1 hour then it's ok otherwise I want to exit with error code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `timeout` command like this :

```
ENTRYPOINT ["timeout", "3600", "python3", "example.py"]
```

If `python3 example.py` takes more than 1 hour (3'600 seconds), an error will be returned (exit code 124).

Comment: Sure, let me try this. Thanks for your reply

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms you're right, thanks for the catch :) I'll update my answer !